# Google checkout merchant-calculation-callback working more than 1 time

Tags: php, google-checkout

Now I am working with Google checkout payment method.When I check the payment with Google checkout sandbox.The XML contain "merchant-calculation-callback" returning two times , How to prevent this problem. Due to this problem, Multiple updates are taking place in my database. How to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Send an acknowlegment back to google that you have notified. If you are using google sample code you can use this code

$Gresponse->SendAck($data[$root]['serial-number'], true);